# How to reduce MSTest execution time in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, mstest

In work we have a test suite that takes about 4 hours to run. I have already cut this down to 2 hours using Phantom JS. However I would like to get this down further.

We are using MsTest with Visual Studio 2013. Most of the tests are written in Specflow.

I would be interested in getting parallel execution working. Is the best way to do this to upgrade to VS 2015? I know I can use Specflow+ but looking for a free option.

What is the best way to reduce the amount of time taken for the tests to run?

Thanks & advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using this project to run all my test(including UI tests) in parallel 
[ParallelTestRunner](https://github.com/sscobici/ParallelTestRunner) it allows you to specify how many treads to run in parallel.

Comment: Hi thanks, I forgot to mention that most of the tests are written in specflow, making things a little more awkward. Do you think this would still work?

Comment: I use specflow as well. You just have to group your test in the right way so that you will be able to run test in parallel. You can also rewrite your test to follow User Journey approach, that will combine a lot of test together and reduce execution time. There are a lot of ways to reduce execution time maybe move some of the test to Integration level or to JavaScript using Karma and Mocha.

Comment: I did some research and Nunit 3.0 supports parallel execution. Add this line to your AssemblyInfo.cs [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] and use nunit as your specflow runner.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm currently trying that. Hopefully the conversion from mstest to NUnit is fairly painless

Comment: Well it was fairly straightforward to convert to NUnit, but I'm running into a problem with the static variable FeatureContext being accessed by more than one test at once. Issue described here. https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/552